# Reading .mat file in android

Tags: android, matlab, opengl-es

Is it possible to read .mat file in android ? how should I convert .mat file to java readable format to use that in android ?

Comment: Do you mean a .mat file?

Comment: "any ideas?" You already described what you need to do. Parse the file into some data-structure, and display that.

Comment: actually it's realtime data , It's always updating so it's not good idea to build a data structure for that ! it takes a lot of memory . I just want .met data to be read by android and visualized directly.

Comment: why don't you write your data into a txt file? this one you can read-in easily.

Comment: actually it's a large amount of realtime data , I'm not sure how can I do that . the android tablet just need to connect to server and get these .mat data in realtime and show the output .

Comment: You can do it more stream-like if you read just the data you need to display at some point in time. But there will still be some kind of data-structure since the data has to be in memory when it is to be displayed.

Comment: actually I want to display the data in some point in time . I wont save any data at all .

Comment: I think using a .mat file is the wrong way to go. Actually, using a file to share realtime data sounds quite dangerous. Maybe you should write a small TCP-server, or something similar, instead?

Comment: I think UDP is better with handling this amount of data in realtime. actually my manager asked me to build a simulink model for sending data through UDP channel but I'm not sure if it works.

Comment: You could have a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071233/how-to-transfer-pictures-from-android-device-to-matlab-and-vice-versa/10071681#10071681)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you don't want to use a .mat file. You can save data in ASCII format with:

```
save output.txt -ascii
```

but I'm not sure that there's an easy way to work out which variable is which when you read this data back in. I assume variables are saved alphabetically, but you will still need to know their size in order to parse them. Or you could save each variable in a different file, if that works for your application.

There is some information on working with .mat files in java [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-9TSRSY/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-9TSRSY). If you're feeling brave, you could try looking at the specification and processing the binary file in java.