# Executing Matlab function from android

Tags: android, matlab

This is what I have to achieve. I have to pass the parameter from an android program to a matlab function that is stored on another server and get back the result in android. I am thoroughly confused as to how to achieve this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the data you want to send/receive is not too tedious, the easiest solution is probably sockets. [Java sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) will be able to connect to and transfer data to/from [matlab sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/). This requires you to have a matlab program running constantly to await a connection.

If you want to e.g. send serialized objects around, then I would suggest writing java code on the server - I think it's not too hard to send serialized objects over a network with sockets. Your java code would then [interface with Matlab](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~whitehouse/matlab/JavaMatlab.html) locally.

I wrote some example sockets code here: [How to transfer pictures from android device to Matlab and vice-versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071233/how-to-transfer-pictures-from-android-device-to-matlab-and-vice-versa/10071681#10071681)

Answer (score 0):

I think [MATLAB Builder™ JA](http://www.mathworks.com/products/javabuilder/) can help you with that but i think that converted code need a  matlab runtime compiler [MCR]
and that will be available i guess soon for android

i was also trying to do some thing like your idea lately but i dropped it and started coding in JAVA an now i am comfortable as i was with matlab:

this link i guess might help you with your problem

http://www.mathworks.se/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/295313